# How to do video summarization based on content using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video-processing

I am a bit confused about this topic. I have done a little object detection for the video. 
Should I summarize according to the objects detected in the video or should I extract key frames from the video that give a good idea about the content ?

I did search for this on the internet ... [I found this](http://mikelrodriguez.com/video-summarization/)

But still I want to know how should I proceed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no answer to that question, this is an open research topic! Pr. Bernard Merialdo from France has been studying this topic for several years. You can have a look at [his research group page and publications](http://bmgroup.eurecom.fr/).